# Enable only those rows which is selected in checkbox for BulkUpdate in Material UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am implementing bulk update in material UI reactjs, and when I select few rows through checkbox then click on "Bulk Update" button then all rows are getting enabled for editing but I want only selected rows to be editied in table.

I am giving "editingMode=Table" and "enableEditing=true" to edit cells in table itself, no need to open dialog box.

// Material table code

```
<MaterialReactTable
  columns={columns}
   data={(userRole.split("|")[1] === "devops") || (userRole.split("|")[1] === "bizops") ? data.filter((dat) => opsEditColumns.includes(dat["Routing Category"])) : data}
  editingMode={tableMode}
  enableEditing={({ original }) => {
  return (userCanEdit) && ((userRole.split("|")[1] === "devops") || (userRole.split("|")[1] === "bizops")) ? opsEditColumns.includes(original["Routing Category"]) : (userRole.split("|")[1] === "bizadmin" || userRole.split("|")[1] === "devadmin") ? true : true;
   }}
 enableRowSelection
 positionPagination="both"
   //getRowId={(row) => row.id}
 initialState={{
 columnVisibility: { ID: false, key: false },
    density: 'compact'
}} //hide 'key' column by default, table row density
muiTableBodyRowProps={({ row }) => ({
    sx: (theme) => ({
        '& td': {
            fontWeight: routingCategory.includes(row.original["Routing Category"]) && timeSlice.includes(row.original.TimeSlice) ? "bold" : "normal"
        },
    }),
})}
muiTableBodyProps={{
    sx: (theme) => ({
        '& tr:nth-of-type(odd)': {
            backgroundColor: "#fdffe0",
        },
    }),
}} // Style every other row
// renderTopToolbarCustomActions={() => {
//     return <Typography>{tableName}</Typography>
// }} // Table title
renderTopToolbarCustomActions={({ table }) => {
    return <>
        <Typography sx={{
            color: 'green',
            display: 'inline',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            mx: 0.5,
            fontSize: 16,
        }}>{tableName}</Typography>
        <Box
            sx={{ display: 'flex', gap: '1rem', p: '0.5rem', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}
        >
            <Button
                color="primary"
                //export all data that is currently in the table (ignore pagination, sorting, filtering, etc.)
                onClick={handleExportData}
                startIcon={<FileDownloadIcon />}
                variant="contained"
            >
                Export All Data
            </Button>
            <Button
                disabled={table.getPrePaginationRowModel().rows.length === 0}
                //export all rows, including from the next page, (still respects filtering and sorting)
                onClick={() =>
                    handleExportRows(table.getPrePaginationRowModel().rows)
                }
                startIcon={<FileDownloadIcon />}
                variant="contained"
            >
                Export All Rows
            </Button>
            <Button
                disabled={table.getRowModel().rows.length === 0}
                //export all rows as seen on the screen (respects pagination, sorting, filtering, etc.)
                onClick={() => handleExportRows(table.getRowModel().rows)}
                startIcon={<FileDownloadIcon />}
                variant="contained"
            >
                Export Page Rows
            </Button>
            <Button
                disabled={
                    !table.getIsSomeRowsSelected() && !table.getIsAllRowsSelected()
                }
                //only export selected rows
                onClick={() => handleExportRows(table.getSelectedRowModel().rows)}
                startIcon={<FileDownloadIcon />}
                variant="contained"
            >
                Export Selected Rows
            </Button>
            <Button
                disabled={isVisible}
                onClick={() => doFetch()}
                startIcon={<RefreshIcon />}
                variant="contained"
            >
                Refresh
            </Button>
            <Button
                disabled={
                    !table.getIsSomeRowsSelected() && !table.getIsAllRowsSelected()
                }
                //export all rows as seen on the screen (respects pagination, sorting, filtering, etc.)
                onClick={e => { hadleBulkUpdate(table) }}
                startIcon={tableMode === "row" ? <EditIcon /> : <FolderSpecialIcon />}
                variant="contained"
            >
                {`${tableMode === "row" ? "Bulk Update" : "Save Bulk Update"}`}
            </Button>
        </Box>
    </>
}} // Custom toolbar
muiTablePaperProps={{
    sx: {
        width: '90%',
        m: 'auto',
    },
}} // Overall table size
muiTableBodyCellProps={{
    sx: {
        borderRight: '1px solid rgba(224,224,224,1)',
 },
}} // Place borders around cells
  onEditingRowSave={handleSaveRowEdits}
  onEditingRowCancel={handleCancelRowEdits}
 />
```

// Handle for button click for bulk update

```
const hadleBulkUpdate = (count) => {        
        if(count > 10) {
            alert("Cannot update more than 10 rows.")
        } else {
            if (tableMode === 'row') {
                setTableMode('table')
            } else {
                setTableMode('row')
            }
        }        
    }
```

API response

```
    Array(20)
0: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_NONREG', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
1: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_NONREG', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
2: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_NONREG', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
3: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_REG', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
4: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_REG', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
5: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_REG', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
6: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_STATUS', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
7: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_STATUS', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
8: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'AH_RPR_ECV_STATUS', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
9: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'BRSPD_FBR', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
10: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'BRSPD_FBR', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
11: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'BRSPD_FBR', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
12: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'CABLE_BRSPD', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
13: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'CABLE_BRSPD', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
14: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'CABLE_BRSPD', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
15: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'DEFAULT_BUS', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
16: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'DEFAULT_BUS', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
17: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'DEFAULT_BUS', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
18: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'DEFAULT_RES', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
19: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'DEFAULT_RES', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
20: {Destination3: 'Internal', Value3: 0, Routing Category: 'DEFAULT_RES', Destination2: 'testData', Value4: 0, …}
```

If I select 3 rows then only 3 rows needs to be enabled in table for editing not all rows of table.

Please help as it is pending since long.

Comment: You provided too little code to understand your problem.

Comment: I have added more code, please check possible solution.

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you want to do, but in the group event handler you should iterate over all the rows, similar to the example:
const handleDeactivate = () => {  table.getSelectedRowModel().flatRows.map((row) => { alert('deactivating ' + row.getValue('name')); }); };